# Neo4j: Updating relationships between existing nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, relationship, updates

I currently have the following model: (Team Leader)-[:leads]->(Team)

As we all know, changes happen within an organization. Today we might have:

```
(Richard)-[:leads]->(Team_1) 

(Henry)-[:leads]->(Team_2)
```

and tomorrow:

```
(Henry)-[:leads]->(Team_1)

(John)-[:leads]->(Team_2) 

(Henry)-[:leads]->(Team_3)
```

My current code is capable of loading a CSV file and do all these changes **EXCEPT** to delete the relationship between Richard and Team_1.

Current implementation I have is the following one:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///TLsandTeams_1st.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE(tl:TL {name: csvLine.TL})
MERGE(t:Team {name: csvLine.Team})
CREATE UNIQUE (tl)-[:leads]->(t)
```

This creates the first scenario described above. Then the second step is:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///TLsandTeams_2nd.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (tl:TL {name : csvLine.TL})
WITH csvLine, tl
MERGE (t:Team {name : csvLine.Team})
WITH tl,t
OPTIONAL MATCH(tl)-[l:leads]->()
WITH tl,t,l
DELETE l
WITH tl,t
MERGE (tl)-[:leads]->(t);
```

This even works for the cases where a team didnt have a team leader associated and now has it and vice-versa. 
As I said before, all changes are correctly put into place except deleting the link between Richard and Team_1. Actually I would like to go even further and delete the Richard node if possible.

I was searching for a way of doing this without having to delete all Team Leader nodes and recreating them again.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for a team lead to lead more than 1 team? If so, your second query would prevent that, and deleting `Richard` would also remove him as leader of any other team.

Comment: Yes it is possible for the same team leader to lead more than 1 team and that is already in place. Only thing missing is deleting Richard and/or the relationship between Richard and Team_1.

Comment: So, the second query is flawed. It will leave `tl` as the team lead of only a single team, `t`.

Comment: Does `TLsandTeams_2nd.csv` contain all the team leads and teams, or just the ones that needed some changes?

Comment: TLsandTeams_2nd.csv contains all the team leads and teams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but, if your OPTIONAL MATCH works on the team instead of the leader:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///TLsandTeams_2nd.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (tl:TL {name : csvLine.TL})
WITH csvLine, tl
MERGE (t:Team {name : csvLine.Team})
WITH tl,t
OPTIONAL MATCH ()-[l:leads]->(t)
WITH tl,t,l
DELETE l
WITH tl,t
MERGE (tl)-[:leads]->(t);
```

Comment: Sylvain, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this creates even more incorrect connections between the Team Leaders and teams.
This makes Henry connected to all teams and Richard continues to be connected to the team that he no longer manages.

Comment: Sylvain, it works! I made a mistake when testing it but I redid the whole steps now and this matches what I needed! Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice! I think it's a "pointer" problem, take a look on this post: https://neo4j.com/blog/moving-relationships-neo4j/